# Filter out data based on dynamic, ARRAYlike column values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have sample data which can be downloaded from [here](https://unice-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/emil_mirzayev_etu_unice_fr/EVc60yfxysxJq4c2OLpYJGIBHN-X72PPom2tpDlv0XyKbw?e=5qKmFY). What I want to do, to filter this data based on `element_counts, cluster_choice_prob_k_fold, benchmark_probabilities` columns for every individual.

This is the logic:
`element_counts` column has an array-like structure [3, 2, 0, 0, 0] (in this case). It shows, how many elements I should select from top values of `benchmark_probabilities` from each top5 `cluster_choice_prob_k_fold` values. In this example, this array tells that:

1. From the biggest`cluster_choice_prob_k_fold` group select 3 values based on their `benchmark_probabilities`
2. From the second biggest `cluster_choice_prob_k_fold` group select 2 values based on their `benchmark_probabilities`
3. From the third biggest `cluster_choice_prob_k_fold` group select 0 values based on their `benchmark_probabilities`
4. Similar to 3
5. Similar to 4.

So, my end result should look like this:

```
individual  cluster_choice_prob_k_fold  benchmark_probabilities element_counts
9710535 0.512776    0.163837    [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
9710535 0.512776    0.0986      [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
9710535 0.512776    0.085191    [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
9710535 0.294674    0.050787    [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
9710535 0.294674    0.037609    [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

For other `individual` values, I have `element_counts` array which look like differently, but always with 5 elements and always element values adding up to 5. How can I do it with Pandas? Difficulty is, to write a function which can take into account different arrays and use it with `groupby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea of solution is create helper column for number of sorted groups and filtering.

Solution working with same values of `element_counts` per each group by `individual` column, also there are always 5 values in lists.

First because sample data are in one column some preprocessing:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
c = df.columns[0].split(',')
df = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(',', expand=True, n=3).applymap(lambda x: x.strip('"'))
df.columns = c
df['individual'] = df['individual'].astype(int)
c = ['cluster_choice_prob_k_fold','benchmark_probabilities']
df[c] = df[c].astype(float)
print (df.head())
   individual  cluster_choice_prob_k_fold  benchmark_probabilities  \
0     9710535                    0.512776                 0.163837   
1     9710535                    0.512776                 0.098600   
2     9710535                    0.512776                 0.085191   
3     9710535                    0.512776                 0.067577   
4     9710535                    0.512776                 0.065420   

    element_counts  
0  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
1  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
2  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
3  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
4  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then sorting per both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and convert string repr of lists to lists of integers by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
df = df.sort_values(['cluster_choice_prob_k_fold','benchmark_probabilities'], ascending=False)
df['element_counts'] = df['element_counts'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Then create counter of groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('individual', sort=False)['cluster_choice_prob_k_fold'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(int)
```

Create new DataFrame with remove duplicates of `individual` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) lists to new column and create column for groups with [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('individual')
         .explode('element_counts')[['individual','element_counts']]
         .assign(g = np.tile(np.arange(5), df['individual'].nunique())))
print (df1)
   individual element_counts  g
0     9710535              3  0
0     9710535              2  1
0     9710535              0  2
0     9710535              0  3
0     9710535              0  4
```

So is possible use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join to original and remove non match groups with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = (df.merge(df1, how='left', on=['individual','g'], suffixes=('','_'))
        .dropna(subset=['element_counts_']))
print (df.head(10))
   individual  cluster_choice_prob_k_fold  benchmark_probabilities  \
0     9710535                    0.512776                 0.163837   
1     9710535                    0.512776                 0.098600   
2     9710535                    0.512776                 0.085191   
3     9710535                    0.512776                 0.067577   
4     9710535                    0.512776                 0.065420   
5     9710535                    0.512776                 0.054764   
6     9710535                    0.512776                 0.048068   
7     9710535                    0.512776                 0.018973   
8     9710535                    0.294674                 0.050787   
9     9710535                    0.294674                 0.037609   

    element_counts  g element_counts_  
0  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
1  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
2  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
3  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
4  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
5  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
6  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
7  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  0               3  
8  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  1               2  
9  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  1               2
```

And last use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) for filter rows per groups by added column, last removed both helper columns:

```
df = (df.groupby(['individual', 'cluster_choice_prob_k_fold'], 
                 group_keys=False, 
                 sort=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.head(x['element_counts_'].iat[0]))
        .drop(['g','element_counts_'], axis=1))
print (df)
   individual  cluster_choice_prob_k_fold  benchmark_probabilities  \
0     9710535                    0.512776                 0.163837   
1     9710535                    0.512776                 0.098600   
2     9710535                    0.512776                 0.085191   
8     9710535                    0.294674                 0.050787   
9     9710535                    0.294674                 0.037609   

    element_counts  
0  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
1  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
2  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
8  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
9  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have an extended version of this dataset where I have 31485 individuals. After I ran this code, my result is a dataframe of shape 5 rows only. I would like to understand the code in a more detailed way if possible. especially, ngroup() part seems unclear to me. It creates for every group within individual an increasing counter. 
I have other `element_counts` values for some `individual`s which are [5, 0, 0, 0, 0] or [2, 1, 1, 1, 0] shape.
I will send you the sample data via email.
Trying to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the solution with pandas.DataFrame.groupby does not come to my mind. However, I wrote a little bit brute force solution that works. If you want to give it a try, here it is (assume `df` being your sample data):

```
dfs = []

for element_count in df.element_counts.unique():
    element_count_list = element_count.strip('[').strip(']').split(', ')
    element_count_list_of_ints = [int(i) for i in element_count_list]
    top_probas = list(df.cluster_choice_prob_k_fold.unique())[:len(element_count_list_of_ints)]

    for n, prob in zip(element_count_list_of_ints, top_probas):
        df_part = df_element\
            .loc[(df.cluster_choice_prob_k_fold == prob) & (df.element_counts == element_count), :]\
            .sort_values(by='benchmark_probabilities', ascending=False)\
            .head(n)\
            .copy()
        dfs.append(df_part)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

The final data frame is following:

```
>>> print(df_final)
   individual  cluster_choice_prob_k_fold  benchmark_probabilities  \
0     9710535                    0.512776                 0.163837   
1     9710535                    0.512776                 0.098600   
2     9710535                    0.512776                 0.085191   
3     9710535                    0.294674                 0.050787   
4     9710535                    0.294674                 0.037609   

    element_counts  
0  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
1  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
2  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
3  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]  
4  [3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! My intuition with groupby was that I write a function which will return True or False based on the selected elements and then I will just assign the result to a column, then filter based on that. The thing is, this is just a sample of the dataset, which is several gbs